# Add publisher to online source with biblatex/biber?

Tags: biblatex

I was told to add a publisher for my online resources but I struggle at how I can add this information behind the auhtor. Is this possible with the "@ONLINE"? Or should I take an different style?

```
\documentclass[
ngerman,
draft
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib}

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum \autocite{zdnetElke} Lorem Ipsum.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Bibliographie.bib:

```
@ONLINE{zdnetElke,
title = {Virtual Private Cloud: Kompromiss zwischen Kosten und rechtlichen Anforderungen},
author = "{Elke Rekowski}",
publisher = {GZDNet},
urldate = {2014-03-19},
url = {http://zdnet.de/41549540/}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only following entry types (fallbacks) use the `publisher` field:

book, collection, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, manual and proceedings.

So you may choose one of those entry types, or you modify the bibdriver-macro for i.e. @online:

Using the package `xpatch` you can easily replace strings from a macro. So if you add following to your MWE:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}{\printfield{note}\newunit\newblock}{\printfield{note}\newunit\newblock%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
}
```

It will add the `publisher+location+date` macro after the `note`-field, which is default place and behaviour for those fields (see bibdrivers of the entry types above).

If you - however - *only* want the field `publisher`, replace the string by:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}{\printfield{note}\newunit\newblock}{\printfield{note}\newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{publisher}%
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Publisher` is not an optional  field for online publications, but `url` and `urldate` are optional fields for books. So I set

```
@BOOK{zdnetElke,
title = {Virtual Private Cloud: Kompromiss zwischen Kosten und rechtlichen Anforderungen},
author = "{Elke Rekowski}",
publisher = {GZDNet},
urldate = {2014-03-19},
url = {http://zdnet.de/41549540/}
}
```

and obtained this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. it seems that i was stuck too hard at the "online" resource. I will do this until I have the time to try out the other answer.