# How to change the order and description of the key terms in the Bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

This question continues my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438515/citation-how-to-add-location-and-publisher-fields-to-the-article-type-of-the-bi).

```
\documentclass[
               english,
               ngerman
              ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
            babel,
            csquotes
           }
\usepackage[
            backend = biber,
            sorting = nyt,
            style = ext-authoryear-comp
           ]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

  @ONLINE{ASTM,
          EDITOR   = {ASTM, International (ASTM)},
          LOCATION = {West Conshohocken, Pennsylvania},
          URL      = {https://www.astm.org/ABOUT/full_overview.html},
          TITLE    = {Detailed Overview},
          URLDATE  = {2018-06-27},
         }

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: position result]

The wished result:

[image: position wish]

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[english, ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel, csquotes}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = ext-authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  urlfrom = {verfügbar unter},
  urlseen = {zuletzt geprüft am},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{urldate}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{url}}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ONLINE{ASTM,
  EDITOR   = {{ASTM International}},
  LOCATION = {West Conshohocken, Pennsylvania},
  URL      = {https://www.astm.org/ABOUT/full_overview.html},
  TITLE    = {Detailed Overview},
  URLDATE  = {2018-06-27},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @moewe! Is the comma necessary after the line `urlseen={zuletzt geprüft am}`?

Comment: @Su-47 No, but I *strongly* suggest you include it, because it will become necessary if a new translation is added after it.